# Spring Cloud Stream - Config Issue - Maven POM.XML for writing a new custom Processor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Could anyone share a sample pom.xml for writing a Spring Cloud Stream (SCS) custom Processor app that uses RabbitMQ for binding?

Also, could you please also shed some light on how do I make my own configs exposed on the SCDF Admin page and how I use the value in my SCS application code.

The intent is to use this app for SCDF flow.

I've built below version looking at some examples.

The application works but I'm seeing [1556 Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70BH8.png) (Some seams to be related to Rabbit MQ config) on the SCDF Admin page when deploying the stream, not sure where and why they are coming from.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.XXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYY</groupId>
<artifactId>my-transformer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<description>Spring Cloud Stream MY Transformer</description>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud-stream.version>Elmhurst.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud-stream.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-starters-build</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-stream.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ADDITIONAL DEPENDENCIES HERE -->

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>kafka-binder</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>rabbit-binder</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the provided [Quick Start](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_quick_start) in user guide. It does exactly what you are looking for and uses Rabbit as an example. Should take no more then 3-4 min

Comment: Hi, Oleg Thank You you for your quick response. I always tried using https://start-scs.cfapps.io/, but the link you referred seems to the place I should have been looking.

Comment: You can also go to http://start.spring.io and then select "cloud stream" and "rabbit binder".

Comment: I picked "Lombok", "Configuration Processor", "PostgreSQL", "Cloud Stream" & "RabbitMQ" from the start.spring.io starter page. The new configurations exposed are lower than before, but I still have 1180. How can I control what can be seen?  For example, the SCDF starter apps hide all excepting to functionally specific fields.

Comment: I still have a problem after I added a new class called MyTransformerProperties and modified my process class to include it with EnableConfigurationProperties
<code>
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyTransformerProperties.class)
public class MyTransformer {

    @Autowired
    private MyTransformerProperties myTransformerProperties;
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EDITransformer.class);

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    @Output(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Object transform(byte[] payload) {</code>

Comment: I got some clue about adding a property called 'configuration-properties.classes' in resource file called 'spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties' to list the classes that are exposing the properties. I'm trying this option now.

Comment: I whitelisted the classes that have properties. The big issue of 1180 configuration has been solved with this now. However, I still have one issue, the property that I exposed in my property class is still not seen on the SCDF admin page at the time of deployment.

Comment: Resolved. I had an incorrect getter method signature.
Thank You Oleg and Soby